# Extrato tipo bancário complexo MySql como resolver

Tags: php, mysql, sqlfiddle

Tenho uma tabela VIEW que preciso extrair dela um extrato, já consegui com ajuda aqui mesmo do stackoverflow progredir para um extrato.

O problema e que agora preciso filtrar mais um pouco este extrato, separando ele
por um determinado ID, mas ao utilizar a WHERE id=emp o resultado do extrato não é mais o mesmo.

segue o link demo: [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/da25b/2)

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `lc_movimento` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pago` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dia` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mes` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ano` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cat` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idemp` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `usu_login` varchar(25) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `descricao` longtext COLLATE latin1_general_ci,
  `obs` longtext COLLATE latin1_general_ci,
  `debito` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `credito` double NOT NULL,
  `dc` varchar(2) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `cat` (`cat`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=3906 ;

INSERT INTO `lc_movimento` (`id`, `pago`, `dia`, `mes`, `ano`, `cat`, `idemp`, `usu_login`, `descricao`, `obs`, `debito`, `credito`, `dc`) VALUES
(41, 1, 11, 8, 2014, 149, 22, 'Rafael', 'SILVA MATTOS 23340-4/4', '', 10, 0, 'D'),
(39, 1, 11, 6, 2014, 149, 22, 'Rafael', 'SILVA MATTOS 23340-2/4', '', 20, 0, 'D'),
(40, 1, 10, 7, 2014, 149, 22, 'Adriano', 'SILVA MATTOS 23340-3/4', '', 30, 0, 'D'),
(33, 1, 16, 5, 2014, 149, 16, 'Adriano', 'WSUL 146511-1/5', '', 0, 1000, 'C'),
(34, 1, 16, 6, 2014, 149, 16, 'Adriano', 'WSUL 146511-2/5', '', 500, 0, 'D'),
(35, 1, 14, 7, 2014, 149, 16, 'Adriano', 'WSUL 146511-3/5', '', 500, 0, 'D'),
(36, 1, 13, 8, 2014, 149, 16, 'Adriano', 'WSUL 146511-4/5', '', 0, 200, 'C'),
(37, 1, 12, 9, 2014, 149, 16, 'Adriano', 'WSUL 146511-5/5', '', 300, 0, 'D'),
(38, 1, 12, 5, 2014, 149, 22, 'Adriano', 'SILVA MATTOS 23340-1/4', '', 0, 800, 'C'),
(28, 1, 2, 5, 2014, 149, 22, 'Adriano', 'MGNETRON 21629-3/3', '', 0, 700, 'C'),
(29, 1, 2, 5, 2014, 149, 22, 'Adriano', 'DELTACAPAS 15092-2/2', '', 100, 0, 'D'),
(30, 1, 14, 5, 2014, 149, 22, 'Adriano', 'DIA-FRAG 72382-1/3', '', 600, 0, 'D'),
(31, 1, 29, 5, 2014, 149, 22, 'Adriano', 'DIA-FRAG 72382-2/3', '', 50, 0, 'D'),
(32, 1, 13, 6, 2014, 149, 22, 'Adriano', 'DIA-FRAG 72382-3/3', '', 0, 60, 'C'),
(42, 1, 2, 5, 2014, 149, 22, 'Adriano', 'RTO 3268-3/3', '', 20, 0, 'D'),
(43, 1, 2, 5, 2014, 149, 22, 'Adriano', 'ROUTE - ENERBRAX 21410-2/2', '', 100, 0, 'D'),
(44, 1, 2, 5, 2015, 149, 22, 'Adriano', 'SILVA MATTOS 23180-1/4', '', 0, 150, 'C'),
(45, 1, 2, 5, 2015, 149, 22, 'Adriano', 'WGK 16339-1/3', '', 100, 0, 'D'),
(46, 1, 2, 5, 2015, 149, 16, 'Adriano', 'ROYALCICLO 35755-1', '', 200, 0, 'D'),
(47, 1, 2, 5, 2015, 149, 22, 'Adriano', 'CAR CENTRAL 42755-1/1', '', 0, 500, 'C');

CREATE VIEW vw_extrato
AS SELECT idemp, concat(lc_movimento.ano,'/',lc_movimento.mes,'/',lc_movimento.dia) as data,
lc_movimento.debito+lc_movimento.credito as valor,
lc_movimento.dc AS tipo
FROM lc_movimento;

SELECT idemp, DATE_FORMAT(data,'%d/%m/%Y') AS data,
    SUM(IF(tipo = 'D', valor, 0)) AS debito,
    SUM(IF(tipo = 'C', valor, 0)) AS credito,
    (SELECT SUM(IF(tipo = 'C', valor, -valor)) FROM vw_extrato AS L2
         WHERE DATE_FORMAT(vw_extrato.data,'%Y%m') >= DATE_FORMAT(L2.data,'%Y%m')
    ) AS saldo
FROM vw_extrato
GROUP BY MONTH(data), YEAR(data) ORDER BY YEAR(data), MONTH(data)
```

Quando eu tento filtrar pelo idemp = '16' resultado não esta correto.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `lc_movimento` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pago` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dia` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mes` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ano` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cat` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idemp` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `usu_login` varchar(25) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `descricao` longtext COLLATE latin1_general_ci,
  `obs` longtext COLLATE latin1_general_ci,
  `debito` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `credito` double NOT NULL,
  `dc` varchar(2) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `cat` (`cat`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=3906 ;

INSERT INTO `lc_movimento` (`id`, `pago`, `dia`, `mes`, `ano`, `cat`, `idemp`, `usu_login`, `descricao`, `obs`, `debito`, `credito`, `dc`) VALUES
(41, 1, 11, 8, 2014, 149, 22, 'Rafael', 'SILVA MATTOS 23340-4/4', '', 10, 0, 'D'),
(39, 1, 11, 6, 2014, 149, 22, 'Rafael', 'SILVA MATTOS 23340-2/4', '', 20, 0, 'D'),
(40, 1, 10, 7, 2014, 149, 22, 'Adriano', 'SILVA MATTOS 23340-3/4', '', 30, 0, 'D'),
(33, 1, 16, 5, 2014, 149, 16, 'Adriano', 'WSUL 146511-1/5', '', 0, 1000, 'C'),
(34, 1, 16, 6, 2014, 149, 16, 'Adriano', 'WSUL 146511-2/5', '', 500, 0, 'D'),
(35, 1, 14, 7, 2014, 149, 16, 'Adriano', 'WSUL 146511-3/5', '', 500, 0, 'D'),
(36, 1, 13, 8, 2014, 149, 16, 'Adriano', 'WSUL 146511-4/5', '', 0, 200, 'C'),
(37, 1, 12, 9, 2014, 149, 16, 'Adriano', 'WSUL 146511-5/5', '', 300, 0, 'D'),
(38, 1, 12, 5, 2014, 149, 22, 'Adriano', 'SILVA MATTOS 23340-1/4', '', 0, 800, 'C'),
(28, 1, 2, 5, 2014, 149, 22, 'Adriano', 'MGNETRON 21629-3/3', '', 0, 700, 'C'),
(29, 1, 2, 5, 2014, 149, 22, 'Adriano', 'DELTACAPAS 15092-2/2', '', 100, 0, 'D'),
(30, 1, 14, 5, 2014, 149, 22, 'Adriano', 'DIA-FRAG 72382-1/3', '', 600, 0, 'D'),
(31, 1, 29, 5, 2014, 149, 22, 'Adriano', 'DIA-FRAG 72382-2/3', '', 50, 0, 'D'),
(32, 1, 13, 6, 2014, 149, 22, 'Adriano', 'DIA-FRAG 72382-3/3', '', 0, 60, 'C'),
(42, 1, 2, 5, 2014, 149, 22, 'Adriano', 'RTO 3268-3/3', '', 20, 0, 'D'),
(43, 1, 2, 5, 2014, 149, 22, 'Adriano', 'ROUTE - ENERBRAX 21410-2/2', '', 100, 0, 'D'),
(44, 1, 2, 5, 2015, 149, 22, 'Adriano', 'SILVA MATTOS 23180-1/4', '', 0, 150, 'C'),
(45, 1, 2, 5, 2015, 149, 22, 'Adriano', 'WGK 16339-1/3', '', 100, 0, 'D'),
(46, 1, 2, 5, 2015, 149, 16, 'Adriano', 'ROYALCICLO 35755-1', '', 200, 0, 'D'),
(47, 1, 2, 5, 2015, 149, 22, 'Adriano', 'CAR CENTRAL 42755-1/1', '', 0, 500, 'C');

CREATE VIEW vw_extrato
AS SELECT idemp, concat(lc_movimento.ano,'/',lc_movimento.mes,'/',lc_movimento.dia) as data,
lc_movimento.debito+lc_movimento.credito as valor,
lc_movimento.dc AS tipo
FROM lc_movimento;


SELECT idemp, DATE_FORMAT(data,'%d/%m/%Y') AS data,
    SUM(IF(tipo = 'D', valor, 0)) AS debito,
    SUM(IF(tipo = 'C', valor, 0)) AS credito,
    (SELECT SUM(IF(tipo = 'C', valor, -valor)) FROM vw_extrato AS L2
         WHERE DATE_FORMAT(vw_extrato.data,'%Y%m') >= DATE_FORMAT(L2.data,'%Y%m')
    ) AS saldo
FROM vw_extrato WHERE idemp = '16'
GROUP BY idemp, MONTH(data), YEAR(data) ORDER BY YEAR(data), MONTH(data)
```

Segue o link demo tentativa de filtro [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/da25b/7/0)

Resultado esperado com a consulta:

```
idemp   data            debito   credito   saldo
16      16/05/2014      0        1000      1000
16      16/06/2014      500      0         500
16      14/07/2014      500      0         0
16      13/08/2014      0        200       200
16      12/09/2014      300      0         -100
16      02/05/2015      200      0         -300
```

Comment: adicionei os códigos na pergunta, independente de estarem no serviço do fiddle. Recomendamos que sempre publique os códigos, e tudo o que for essencial a pergunta, aqui mesmo no stack.

Comment: Qual é o resultado obtido (a fim de que possa ser comparado com o esperado)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creio que o problema é que sua sub-consulta também busca dados de vw_extrato sem filtrar por idemp, então a subconsulta está somando valores de todo mundo na hora de determinar o saldo.

Adicionando este filtro parece estar ok:

```
SELECT idemp, DATE_FORMAT(data,'%d/%m/%Y') AS data,
SUM(IF(tipo = 'D', valor, 0)) AS debito,
SUM(IF(tipo = 'C', valor, 0)) AS credito,
(SELECT SUM(IF(tipo = 'C', valor, -valor)) FROM vw_extrato AS L2
      WHERE DATE_FORMAT(vw_extrato.data,'%Y%m') >=
          DATE_FORMAT(L2.data,'%Y%m') and
          idemp = vw_extrato.idemp) AS saldo
FROM vw_extrato WHERE idemp = '16' 
GROUP BY idemp, MONTH(data), YEAR(data) ORDER BY YEAR(data), MONTH(data);

+-------+------------+--------+---------+-------+
| idemp | data       | debito | credito | saldo |
+-------+------------+--------+---------+-------+
|    16 | 16/05/2014 |      0 |    1000 |  1000 |
|    16 | 16/06/2014 |    500 |       0 |   500 |
|    16 | 14/07/2014 |    500 |       0 |     0 |
|    16 | 13/08/2014 |      0 |     200 |   200 |
|    16 | 12/09/2014 |    300 |       0 |  -100 |
|    16 | 02/05/2015 |    200 |       0 |  -300 |
+-------+------------+--------+---------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Exato, isto mesmo o resultado esperado atingido.