# soma dos valores PHP e MySql

Tags: php, mysql

Boa tarde,
Amigos estou criando aqui um sistema de notinhas para usar na empresa ele e bem basico, mas estou com duvida em como montar a função de pagamento para que ele identifique os valores some de baixa no valor pago e crie um saldo. minha tabela e da seguinte forma

```
id | cliente | valor | pago | Deb/Cred
1  | teste   | 35.00 | N    | D
2  | teste   | 35.00 | N    | D
3  | teste   | 35.00 | N    | D
4  | pago    | 65.00 | S    | C
5  | saldo   | 40.00 | N    | C
```

Ai gostaria de saber como montar a formula em php para que quando eu for lançar o pagamento ele somar os valores ate o id 3 que sao apenas debitos que da um valor de 105.00 subtrair o pagamento que esta no id 4 que e um credito pegando o resultado que e 105.00-65.00=40.00 lançar no id 5 como credito e subistituir na coluna pago o N por S para identificar que esta pago

Comment: Esses valores `pago` e `saldo` estão sendo inseridos também nessa mesma tabela? É isso mesmo?

Comment: O valor pago ele e inserido a cada pagamento, o saldo e o resultado dos valores testes - pago. e todos ficam apenas em uma tabela sendo que quando houver um pagamento quero mudar o valor "N" da coluna pago para "S" e acrescentar o saldo

Comment: Não está claro a sua dúvida... Quando o cliente pagar uma dessas parcelas, você vai atualizar a linha `pago` e adicionar o quanto ele pagou? Ou só marcará a parcela como `S`?

Comment: Entao Marcelo, queria que quando uma pessoa pagasse ele soma a divida com o valor pago marque todas as dividas e lançe uma nova divida com o restante que seria o saldo para que quando eu for emitir uma nota de cobrança nao emitir todo o relatorio e sim apenas apos o lançamento do ultimo saldo. vamos por um exemplo igual na id 4 ele pagou e gerou um saldo(debito/credito) ai nas id´s acima seria dado um update e inserido S na coluna pago na id 5 vamos supor que ele faça mais 5 compras a ultima compra seria o id 10 pagaria iria ter um id 11 com o valor pago e o id 12 com o saldo(debito/credito)

Comment: Sim, foi isso mesmo que entendi mas você está utilizando uma única tabela para isso? Se realmente precisas de um registro contendo o valor pago e o saldo restante, você poderia ter uma outra tabela relacionada e com esses registros. Nesse exemplo da sua pergunta, o cliente tem 3 compras no valor de 35 e pagou 65, isso quer dizer que é possível ele efetuar um pagamento de uma parcela dessas com valor menor que o total?

Comment: Isso mesmo, um exemplo e esse post aqui,

http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/86151/extrato-tipo-banc%C3%A1rio-complexo-mysql-como-resolver

mas a questao e que eu nao quero que exiba no relatorio os valores ja pago apenas do ultimo pagamento em diante

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40659/discussion-between-cristiano-cardoso-silva-and-marcelo-de-andrade).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pessoal consegui resolver com o seguinte SELECT

```
SELECT
(SELECT SUM(IF(debito_credito_financeiro = 'C', valor_financeiro, -valor_financeiro)) FROM cad_financeiro WHERE cad_financeiro.pago_financeiro = 'N') AS saldo
FROM cad_financeiro
JOIN cad_trabalho ON cad_financeiro.id_trabalho = cad_trabalho.id_trabalho
JOIN cad_paciente ON cad_trabalho.id_paciente = cad_paciente.id_paciente
JOIN cad_cliente ON cad_paciente.id_cliente = cad_cliente.id_cliente
WHERE cad_cliente.id_cliente = '$id'
GROUP BY cad_cliente.id_cliente
```

e criando uma função no php para dar um UPDATE no bd