# Criar um Viewer de tres tabelas

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli, sql-select

Como criar um view no mysql com 3 tabelas

sendo a seguinte estrutura

```
cliente
  |id_cliente
  |nome_cliente

produto
  |id_produto
  |nome_produto
  |valor_produto

pedido
  |id_pedido
  |id_produto
  |id_cliente
```

gostaria de criar um view com a seguinte estrutura

```
vw_pedido
  |id_vw_pedido
  |id_cliente_vw_pedido
  |nome_cliente_vw_pedido
  |id_produto_vw_pedido
  |nome_produto_vw_pedido
  |valor_produto_vw_pedido
```

Comment: Ela é um select com join dos campos relacionados.

Comment: Ok, Muito Obrigado Rray, poderia me ajudar em outro post?

Comment: Qual? tem o link ai

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/133798/emitir-extrato-de-servi%C3%A7os

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seria mais o menos isso o select da sua View..

```
SELECT PEDIDO.ID_PEDIDO,
CLIENTE.ID_CLIENTE,
CLIENTE.NOME_CLIENTE,
PRODUTO.ID_PRODUTO,
PRODUTO.VALOR_PRODUTO
FROM PEDIDO, CLIENTE, PRODUTO
WHERE 1=1
AND PRODUTO.ID_PRODUTO = PEDIDO.ID_PRODUTO
AND CLIENTE.ID_CLIENTE = PEDIDO.ID_CLIENTE
```